# About twins (similiar and non similar)

Tags: word-request

How do you call to a "non similar" twins? I know there is a word to refer to the non similar twins.

Comment: Did you check the wikipedia page for [twin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin)? The answer is literally in the second sentence of the entry.  The scientific term is "dizygotic" and the more common term is "fraternal."

Answer (score 3):

There are *identical* twins and *fraternal* twins. The word you are looking for is *fraternal*.

> Fraternal, nonidentical, or dizygotic twins occur from two different eggs, each fertilized by a different sperm. Therefore, fraternal twins have the same genetic resemblance as any pair of siblings (about half their genes in common).
>
> (source: Steiner-Grossman, 1997)

Answer (score 0):

The word you are looking for is [Fraternal Twins](https://www.google.com/search?ei=JWgNW4fOA6TcjwTBgZRY&q=fraternal%20twins%20definition&oq=fraternal%20twins%20d&gs_l=psy-ab.1.1.0i20i264k1j0l9.5945.6687.0.7807.2.2.0.0.0.0.90.179.2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.2.178...0i67k1.0.tLp4orKCFKc)